# Magento multiple languages english not functioning

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a problem with my Magento store. I have been working on 2 store views and they were functioning fine. Now i have been working on some performance issues and fixed those, but my english version of the shop does not function anymore. It uses the right theme but doesn't show up with right stuff.

The sidebar's are from the starting store, and are not the same as my dutch store. The topbar is different and the logo does not show. I dont know what is going wrong, i have been searching for the problem but i didn't found it yet.

Any ideas?

Store is: http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you fixed your performance issues in a proper way... after playing around to get an idea of the problem I suddenly got `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections`

1. Turn off the developer mode on a live system!!!
2. What kind of 'fixes' have you done to deal with the performance issues? This maybe gives some help to identify your problem...
3. Have you flushed the caches?

Sorry for popping your store...

Comment: The problem there was that my whole server got attacked DDOS...

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. Anyway, can you give some further information as asked?